# Complexity where inner loop depends on outer loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, big-o, pseudocode

For the following pseudocode, I would like to work out the number of operations as a function in input size `n` before putting it into **Big-O-Notation**:

```
for i ← 1 to n do
    for j ← 3 to 3i+n do
        // operation
```

So far, I think that the inner loop is equal to `3i + n - 2` operations for each iteration of the outer loop `n`. Yielding

```
n (3i + n - 2) = n^2 - 2n + 3ni
```

which simplifies to `O(n^2)`.

But I'm not sure if I'm on the right track as I haven't seen any questions like this where the index of the outer loop is used in the inner loop.

Comment: Yes, `O(n^2)` looks like it is an upper bound for your loop.  You can probably make the bound tighter with some math.

Comment: You can't. It is in `Theta(n^2)` (bound from both sides by `n^2`, it grows equally strong).

Comment: with some analytic algebra exec-time converges to `3n((n+1)/2-1)+n^2` which approaches `5/2n^2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, it is in `O(n^2)`. Even more than that, it is in `Theta(n^2)`.

---

### Explanation

The only thing that matters is how often `// operation` is getting executed. The computations for the loop itself, like the indices are all in `Theta(1)`, so we can ignore them.

Therefore, count how often `// operation` is executed. That is `n * (3i + n - 2)`, like you said.

However, the `i` changes. So you actually need to fully write it out:

[image: whole function]

Simplify this:

[image: simplification]

Which clearly is in `Theta(n^2)`.

---

### Formal definition proof

You can easily show that with the formal definition. Therefore, let us call the function `f`. We have

[image: bounded from above]

so it is in `O(n^2)`. And we have

[image: bounded from below]

yielding `Omega(n^2)`. Together this means `f in Theta(n^2)`.

I chose the constants randomly. You could make it tighter, but you only need to find one for which it holds, so it doesn't matter.

---

### Limit definition proof

Of course we could also easily show it using the limit definitions:

[image: limit proof]

Which is `> 0` and `< inf`, so `f in Theta(n^2)` (see [Wikipedia:Big-O-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)).

The table for the results is

- `< inf` is `O(g)`
- `> 0` is `Omega(g)`
- `= 0` is `o(g)`
- `= inf` is `omega(g)`.
- `> 0 and < inf` is `Theta(g)`

For the limits we used **L'Hôpital's rule** (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)) which informally says:

> The limit of `f/g` is the same as the limit of `f'/g'`, supposed the limit even exists.

---

### Note

The analysis assumed that `// operation` is in `Theta(1)`, otherwise you will need to account for its complexity too, obviously.

Comment: it's precisely O(2n^2)

Comment: @Abra001 Both are the exact same sets: `O(2n^2) = O(n^2)`. And it's `Theta` additionally.