# Time complexity of nested for loops where inner loop depends on outer loop

Tags: java, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I have a nested for loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
   for(j = 0; j <= i/5; j++)
      print("Hello World!");
```

How do I find the time complexity of this loop.

I was thinking for the outer loop, it runs from 0 to n^2 (exclusive), so it runs n^2 + 1 times.

For the inner loop, it depends on i and this is where I get lost. Any pointers?

Comment: You need a little bit of math to calculate correctly the complexity. Something quite similar is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355125/complexity-where-inner-loop-depends-on-outer-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost always you can just plug in numbers that common sense tells you comprise the worst case scenario. Unless said worst case is guaranteed to only run a fixed amount of times regardless of N (i.e. all loops are near-optimal, except for at most 5 loops which aren't, even if we loop a thousand times - very rare) - then just do the math with the worst case.

This goes as far as each individual loop: Take the worst case for each. This is right, unless there is a link between the loops, e.g. if the inner loop runs 'worst case' only if some outer loop is guaranteed to run best case, and vice versa - when there is a clear relationship.

So, let's apply it here:

- i runs from 0 to n*n, that part is easy.
- j runs from 0 to i (we can ignore constant factors, so that `/5` part is irrelevant, and we can forget about it).

The j loop's worst case is that i is equal to `n*n`, which makes j run from 0 to `n*n`. So let's just use that.

This is in fact the right answer; this is a loop that runs for `n*n` iterations (This is the `j` loop), and this process is repeated `n*n` times (The `i` loop), for a total complexity of `O(n^4)` (ouch, that's gonna fall over pretty quickly as n grows).

If you are unsure if the math works out, try to find linearity. That guarantees it. In this case, the best case scenario is when `i` is 0, in which case the j loop runs only once, vs. the worst case where the j loop runs `n*n` times. Crucially, the characteristic of the `j` loop is linear: Just chart out what happens to the performance of the j loop over the 'lifetime' of the i loop, and it's a simple straight relationship. First 5 j loops run once, second 5 j loops run twice, all the way up to the last j loop which runs `n*n/5` times.

The 'average' of all j loops is this simply the middle of that line: half of `n*n/5`. Which is `n*n/10`, and constant factors do not matter, so that's still `n*n`. Hence why this is `O(n^4)`, the same as `for (j = 0; j < n*n; j++)` would have been.

Comment: Are these loops vectorizable ? Since the inner loop index depends on the outer loop my understanding tells me they are not vectorizable

Comment: Define 'vectorizable'.

Comment: I meant applying operations to whole arrays instead of individual array elements

Comment: The JVM makes no promises either way. However, 'oh this just runs on an entire array' doesn't let you dodge `O(n*n*n*n)` characteristics. In fact, 'is it vectorizable' is __utterly irrelevant__ to big-O notation (which, primarily, indicates how big-O notation has its limits. It's painting with a a _very_ rough brush). The JVM is definitely not going to farm the work out to a GFX card for massive parallellization (and even if, that _still_ does not affect big-O. GFX cards can't run things infinitely in parallel, hence, big-O does not care).

Comment: FWIW, the JVM will usually  use parallellization facilities on CPU, will not use parallellization features of GPU and the like, and may not use the CPU especially if the CPU does not let you make 64-bit width sub-ops. Project Panama is trying to fix that last part; it's not in the java18 release though. One day soon it will be hopefully.